# The progenitor of libraries

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> Perhaps you know me, I come in many forms,
> Regarding cultures, I am their only norm.
>
> As common as the days of the year, I exist,
> Yearning for the truth? Come to me, I insist.
>
> Evoked in times of war and peace to help you,
> Right here I'll wait for all the faithful and true.

What am I?

Comment: Can someone explain why they downvoted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Religion

Perhaps you know me, I come in many forms, 
Regarding cultures, I am their only norm.

> There is no scholarly consensus over what precisely constitutes a religion but there is a general idea of connecting the physical with the supernatural. In particular, it is difficult to find a culture which does not have some religious element.

As common as the days of the year, I exist, 
Yearning for the truth? Come to me, I insist.

> There are an estimated 10,000 distinct religions worldwide practised by more than 80% of the world's population. A search for supernatural truth is a common theme.

Evoked in times of war and peace to help you,

> Religion has been used both to incite war and call for peace

Right here I'll wait for all the faithful and true.

> Religion often requires a leap of faith.

Hidden Hint

> The letters at the start of each line spell out PRAYER

Comment: Much better than mine :-)

Comment: This is correct, good job.

Comment: @Phylyp I just gave you +1. Sorry, I had not seen your answer before posting mine but it seems both are along the same lines.

Comment: @hexomino , thank you, and reciprocated. Our answers might be along the same lines, but there's a key difference: yours is correct, and mine was 'close but no cigar' :-)

Answer (score 5):

You are a

> **TEMPLE**
>  *i.e. as a general place of worship, not specifically a Hindu/Buddhist temple*

Perhaps you know me, I come in many forms,
Regarding cultures, I am their only norm.

> There are many forms of temples and places of worship
>  The form a cornerstone of the culture of any civilization

As common as the days of the year, I exist,

> There are numerous temples/places of worship

Yearning for the truth? Come to me, I insist.

> Temples are a place where people have often gone seeking answers

Evoked in times of war and peace to help you,

> Prayers, offerings and sacrifices are made in temples in times of war, and peacetime

Right here I'll wait for all the faithful and true.

> Temples are at a fixed place, and always ready to welcome believers

Title: The progenitor of libraries

> Temples were often the seats of learning in ancient days, and a place where scientific advancements were made, before the separation of science and religion between libraries and temples.

Hidden hint:

> The first letter of each line spells PRAYER, which is an activity commonly performed at temples.

Comment: This is close, but it's not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> Science

Perhaps you know me, I come in many forms,
Regarding cultures, I am their only norm.

> science comes in many forms(math, physics, chemistry, ...) regardless
>  of culture, everyone use science

As common as the days of the year, I exist,

> there are billions of branches of science

Yearning for the truth? Come to me, I insist.

> Science pushes away all sorts of superstitions

Evoked in times of war and peace to help you,

> In wars science is used to defend or attack, and in peace makes societies thrive

Right here I'll wait for all the faithful and true.

> only those can push superstitions away can truly embrace science

Title: The progenitor of libraries

> because of love of science libraries were made

Comment: This is a great answer, but not quite right.